# Take a list from a method and use it in another method

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

In my Orange class I have this method:

```
    public static List<Orange> AddOrange()
    {
        List<Orange> oranges = new List<Orange>();
        oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 150, Measure = 6 });
        oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 160, Measure = 6 });
        oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 160, Measure = 6 });
        oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 150, Measure = 6 });
        oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 160, Measure = 6 });
        oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 160, Measure = 6 });

        return oranges;
    }
```

And in my OrangeJuice class I have this method

```
public static int CreateJuice(List<Orange> oranges )
    {
        var bottle = new Bottle();
        var bottle2 = new Bottle();
        var cork = new Cork();
        var cork2 = new Cork();

        var orangeJuice = new OrangeJuice(1, 33, oranges, bottle, cork, 20);
        var orangeJuice2 = new OrangeJuice(2,33,oranges, bottle2,cork2, 20);

        var order = new Order();
        order.OrangeJuices.Add(orangeJuice);
        order.OrangeJuices.Add(orangeJuice2);

        var totalPrice = order.OrangeJuices.Sum(x => x.Price);

        return totalPrice;
    }
```

What I want to do to take the oranges I created on AddOrange method (six oranges) and put them in the CreateJuice method. So I get the list from the first method must somehow into the second method.

I'm wondering if I'm doing it correctly? And if not, how can I solve it?

Comment: You are doing it correctly! oragnes is your list of oranges in CreateJuice

Comment: Where do you call the first method?  It looks like the first method returns a list of oranges and the second method accepts a list of oranges.  So whatever code is calling these methods would handle that.

Comment: var myJuice = CreateJuice(AddOrange());

Comment: I have not called the first method (AddOrange) yet. I'm not sure how and where I can call it. All I want to do is to take the list from AddOrange method and insert it so I can create OrangeJuice

Comment: @slugster I think that's exactly what the OP is looking for. +1.

Comment: I can't get it to work!
When I type in this code:
var totalSum = OrangeJuice.CreateJuice(AddOranges());

I get this error: The name AddOranges does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2):

Normally the method called `AddOrange` should have been named as `GetOranges`

```
public static List<Orange> GetOranges()
{
    List<Orange> oranges = new List<Orange>();
    oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 150, Measure = 6 });
    oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 160, Measure = 6 });
    oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 160, Measure = 6 });
    oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 150, Measure = 6 });
    oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 160, Measure = 6 });
    oranges.Add(new Orange() { Weight = 160, Measure = 6 });
    return oranges;
}
```

Then in the place you call the `CreateJuice` in you code, you only have to pass `GetOranges`.

```
CreateJuice(GetOranges());
```

or

```
var oranges = GetOranges();
var juice = CreateJuice(oranges);
```